# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion

As all we know many beta sites look the same and it would be nice to be distinguished somehow.

Jeff Atwood wrote a blog post about it:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/

Maybe an idea stemming from the community will be taken into account ;).

Do you have any interesting proposals?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the time to be looking at this. Logo and design are attributes of a graduated site, which is likely to be a year or more down the line.

Comment: That feel when I close my own post :). I'll try to reopen it after a year. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please read [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta) instead of Stack Exchange's obsolete blog posts. Sites get a design after they graduate, which usually takes a couple of years these days.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't seen that before. What was the shortest time to graduate during last year?

Comment: @belford That will be a while. With the design-independent graduations popping up, a site can "graduate" without getting a design. That will take a long time, and the designers from SE will come to us when the time is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in beta. Trust me, it will be a loooong time before you get out of it. Think about design when you go public, and then when you graduated.

[image]

I think that looks beautiful.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.. :^)